# Preventing a User From Having Multiple Concurrent Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for preventing multiple concurrent sessions for a user.

What I need for example, once a user signs in, the app would invalidate and effectively "sign out" all other users. Then, the old sessions would be redirected to the sign in page.

The software that I work on is using the Identity server provider type

I tried to add this code in the web.config file:

```
<add name="SingleSessionEnforcement" type="SingleSessionEnforcement" />
```

[image: config image]

But it returns an error when I open the site:

[image: exception image]

Any tips on how to do this?